# Building a second time causes Always CopyToOutputDirectory files to be deleted

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution with a project containing a few cs files and a few xml files. Upon building from scratch, the cs turn to a dll and get transferred to the output directory, and so are the xmls. 
 
On the second time I build though, it builds this project, with nothing changed, and the xmls are gone from the output directory (instead of just being replaced of course). Every file is marked as: Build Action Content and CopyToOutputDirectory Always. 
I seriously don't know the problem. If anyone has anything, please share. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of visual studio/IDE are you using?

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2017, 15.6 update